# error when trying to import spark with sbt

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I downloaded play framwork project - the simple one. I'm trying to import spark version 2.2.0 via sbt but I'm getting the next error :

```
sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.2.0: not found
```

The build.sbt file :

```
name := """play-scala-starter-example"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)
resolvers += Resolver.sonatypeRepo("snapshots")
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"
libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test
libraryDependencies += "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.196"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"
```

All the lines in the build.sbt files are marked in red and have the same error :

```
expression type must conform to setting in sbt file
```

The plugin.sbt file :

```
// The Play plugin
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.13")
```

To clarify, I have two problems :

1. "expression type must conform to setting in" in the build.sbt file for every row.
2. Can't import the spark libraries via sbt

Comment: v2.2.0 only appears to be available for spark-core_2.10 and spark-core_2.11 (_not_ 2.12): https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core

Comment: ^That is correct Spark doesn't support Scala 2.12 yet

Comment: I dont see any spark version that is suitable for scala 2.12 right ? So I should use a different scala version ? Do you have any idea about the first error I got ?

Comment: I changed the import line to : libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0" and now it works. However when I try to open one of my scala files with scala console it opens scala console version 2.12.4, why is that?

Comment: @Mariel Are you running `sbt console` from your root project directory? If so, it will run the Scala version that you specified in your build.sbt, i.e. 2.12.4. You may have to change that.

Comment: @Jubobs I changed it but stil the console from a different version. Moreover, I'm getting an error on all the lines after guice in the build.sbt : unkown artificat Not resolved or indexes. I restarted inteliJ but it didnt help.. I'm trying to use spark..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark 2.2.0 is built and distributed to work with Scala 2.11 by default. To write applications in Scala, you will need to use a compatible Scala version (e.g. 2.11.X). And your scala version is 2.12.X. That's why it is throwing exception.

Comment: I changed the import line to : libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.2.0" and now it works. However when I try to open one of my scala files with scala console it opens scala console version 2.12.4, why is that?

Comment: Strange behaviour no idea.